# How can I make modifications to the current element in a For loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
for i in A:
    if i < 0:
        A[i] == abs(i)
```

How can I use the current element in the for loop, I want to make the current element positive if it is negative.

Comment: What type is `A`? This should work if it's a dictionary, it won't work for a list.

Comment: `==` is for equality, use `=`

Comment: in python we offen create new list with new values and assign to old variable.

Comment: @MitchelPaulin lol, usually the error is the other way.

Comment: Can you give an example of what `A` is?

Comment: @busybear its a list

Answer (score 1):

`i` here is the *value* of each item in your list. Conventionally, `i` refers to an index, which has led you to write `A[i]` to refer to the current element. But `A[i]` isn't what you want, and it could even be an error, depending on the values in `A`.

You need the index to change values in the list. One way to get an index is to use `enumerate()`:

```
for index, value in enumerate(A):
    if value < 0:
        A[index] = abs(value)
```

Note the use of meaningful variable names so you don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `for i in A` then in each iteration `i` will be an element in A, not an interative index. What you want to do is something like this:

```
for i, element in enumerate(A):
    if element < 0:
        A[i] = abs(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate()` to iterate over both the elements and indexes of a list. If you just iterate over the list normally, `i` is the list element, not the index, so it makes no sense to use `A[i]`.

```
for i, el in enumerate(A):
    if el < 0:
        A[i] = abs(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the enumerate functionality of python3 standard library to achieve your goal. For example if you had the following:

```
A = [4, 2, -3, 5, -2]
```

You could say:

```
for index, value in A:
    if value < 0:
        A[index] = abs(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in a list comprehension:

```
A = [abs(x) if x < 0 else x for x in A ]
```

Comment: This can be shortened to `[abs(x) for x in A]`

Comment: yes it can but since their original code had an if statement I wanted to stay true to that to show them how that statement would work in a list comprehension